# html open xslt and pass variable

Tags: xslt

Am looking for some assistance, I've been searching the web for over a week now trying to expand my limited knowledge of searching an xml file to find a specific entry based on a users input from an html form.

I have tried xpath but my javascripting knowledge is limited and i couldn't get this to work.

I have resorted to xsl to style my xml, it works really nicely when i hardcode what i'm looking for, i'd very much like to make this dynamic based on my html from input, however i'm really struggling with the code to get this working, there are also few examples of how to setup the html side of things that i've found.

XSL

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
  <xsl:param name="skuid" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//sku[@id=$skuid]" />
  </xsl:template>
  
    <xsl:template match="sku">
<html>
  <body>
<h2>Availability:</h2>

  <table border="1">
    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
      <th>Sku Code</th>
      <th>Description</th>
   <th>Due Date</th>
   <th>Due Qty</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
      <td align="center"><xsl:value-of select="skucode"/></td>
      <td align="center"><xsl:value-of select="description"/></td>
   <td align="center"><xsl:value-of select="duedate"/></td>
   <td align="center"><xsl:value-of select="dueqty"/></td>
 </tr>
 <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
   <th colspan="2" align="center">Ranged Currrent Cat</th>
   <th colspan="2" align="center">Ranged Next Cat</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
   <td colspan="2" align="center"><xsl:value-of select="currcat"/></td>
   <td colspan="2" align="center"><xsl:value-of select="nextcat"/></td>
    </tr>   
  </table>
  </body>
  </html>
 </xsl:template>
  

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="employees2.xsl"?>
<availability>
<sku id="10011">
<skucode>10011</skucode>
<description>4 Gallon Loft Tank Kit</description>
<duedate>07/09/2016</duedate>
<dueqty>10.00</dueqty>
<currcat>Main Cat In Store</currcat>
<nextcat>Main Cat In Store</nextcat>
</sku>
<sku id="10018">
<skucode>10018</skucode>
<description>MATT EMULSION PINK 2/5L</description>
<duedate>09/09/2016</duedate>
<dueqty>100</dueqty>
<currcat>Not Ranged</currcat>
<nextcat>Not Ranged</nextcat>
</sku>
<sku id="12345">
<skucode>12345</skucode>
<description>DeWalt Drill</description>
<duedate>10/09/2016</duedate>
<dueqty>1000</dueqty>
<currcat>Main Cat In Store</currcat>
<nextcat>Main Cat In Store</nextcat>
</sku>
<sku id="98765">
<skucode>98765</skucode>
<description>Wheel Barrow</description>
<duedate>31/09/2016</duedate>
<dueqty>1</dueqty>
<currcat>Not Ranged</currcat>
<nextcat>Not Ranged</nextcat>
</sku>
</availability>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
SKU: <input type="text" name="SKU" id="input" maxlength="5">
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onClick="loadXMLDoc()">
<br />
<br />
<div id="results"></div>

<script>

function loadXMLDoc(dname)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {
  xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xhttp.open("GET",dname,false);
try {xhttp.responseType="msxml-document"} catch(err) {} // Helping IE
xhttp.send("");
return xhttp;
}
var y = document.getElementById("input").value;
var x=loadXMLDoc("employees.xml");
var xml=x.responseXML;
path="/Availability/sku[@id=y]";

// code for IE
if (window.ActiveXObject || xhttp.responseType=="msxml-document")
{
xml.setProperty("SelectionLanguage","XPath");
nodes=xml.selectNodes(path);
for (i=0;i<nodes.length;i++)
  {
  document.write(nodes[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write("<br>");
  }
}

// code for Chrome, Firefox, Opera, etc.
else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument)
{
var nodes=xml.evaluate(path, xml, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
var result=nodes.iterateNext();

while (result)
  {
  document.write(result.childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write("<br>");
  result=nodes.iterateNext();
  }
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

kind regards
Paul

Comment: Welcome to SO @PaulWills :-) Can you elaborate a bit on "I couldn't get this to work" ? What exactly happens? Are you referencing you xslt anywhere in the html? Any errors showing up in console?

Answer (score 0):

In your path expression

path="/Availability/sku[@id=y]";

"y" means "the value of the element child of the sku element with name "y", it doesn't mean "the value of the Javascript variable named "y".

I forget whether the browser DOM XPath API has a mechanism for substituting parameter values; if not you can use string concatenation to create a path expression containing the value of y as a string literal. But beware injection attacks.